# Excluding Outliers from Avg Calculations at the dimension level in Qlik

Tags: average, qlikview, outliers, qliksense

All,

I need to plot monthly average trend. Each month behaves differently hence the need to exclude outliers at the month level. This calculation needs to be dynamic if I need to look at the trend by a certain category (the outliers need to be recalculated at the category level by each month)

here is what I tried:

I created a variable 
`vOutlier = Fractile(count , 0.75 ) +  1.5 *(Fractile(count , 0.75 ) - Fractile(count , 0.25 ))`

then I used it in the set analysis 
`avg({$<Values = {"<=Fractile(Values , 0.75 ) +  1.5 *(Fractile(Values , 0.75 ) - Fractile(Values , 0.25 ))"}>} Values)`
and `avg({$<Values = {"<=$(=$(vOutliers))"}>} Values)`

If you need a sample QVF, please find it [here](https://community.qlik.com/message/1384320#1384320) on the Qlik forum.